# In memory database, with hibernate and periodically persisting to an actual db

Tags: spring, hibernate, in-memory-database

I would like to use an in memory db with hibernate, so my queries are super quick. 
But moreover i would like to periodically persist that in memory state into a real mysql db.
Ofcourse the in memory database should load its initial content on startup from that mysql db.
Are there any good frameworks/practices for that purpose?   (Im using spring)  any tutorials or pointers will help.

Comment: Try using a session and the second level cache, see bellow

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest with you, most decent databases can be considered in-memory to an *extent* given that they cache data and try not to hit the hard-disk as often as they can.  In my experience the best in-memory databases are either caches, or alagamations of other data sources that are already persisted in some other form, and then are updated in a live fashion for time-critical information, or refreshed periodically for non-time-critical information.

Loading data from a cold start in to memory is potentially a lengthy process, but subsequent queries are going to be super-quick.

If you are trying to cache what's already persisted you can look at memcache, but in essence in memory databases always rely on a more persistent source, be it MySQL, SQLServer, Cassandra, MongoDB, you name it.

So it's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve, suffice to say it is possible to bring data in from persistent databases and have a massive in memory cache, but you need to design around how stale certain data can get, and how often you need to hit the *real* source for up-to-the-second results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the simplest would be to use some core Hibernate features for that, use the hibernate `Session` itself and combine it with the second level cache.

Declare the entities you want to cache as `@Cacheable`:

```
@Entity 
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NON_STRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class SomeReferenceData { ... }
```

Then implement the periodically flushing like this, supposing you are using JPA:

- open an EntityManager
- load the entities you want to cache using that entity manager and no other
- Keep the entity manager opened until the next periodic flush, Hibernate is keeping track what instances of SomeReferenceData where modified  in-memory via it's dirty checking mechanism, but no modification queries are being issued.
- Reads on the database are being prevented via the second level cache
- When the moment comes to flush the session, just begin a transaction and commit immediately.
- Hibernate will update modified entities in the database, update the second level cache and resume execution
- eventually close the entity manager and replace it with a new one, if you want to reload from the database eveything
- otherwise keep the same entity manager open

**code example:**

Try this code to see the overall idea:

```
public class PeriodicDBSynchronizeTest {

    @Test
    public void testSynch() {

        // create the entity manager, and keep it
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testModel");

        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        // kept in memory due to @Cacheable
        SomeReferenceData ref1 = em.find(SomeReferenceData.class, 1L);
        SomeReferenceData ref2 = em.find(SomeReferenceData.class, 2L);
        SomeReferenceData ref3 = em.find(SomeReferenceData.class, 3L);  
        ....  

        // modification are tracked but not committed
        ref1.setCode("005");

        // these two lines will flush the modifications into the database
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

       // continue using the ref data, and tracking modifications until the next request
       ...
    }
}
```